# iOS 8 scale app to different screensizes

Tags: ios, layout, storyboard

i have a short question for developping an iOS 8 App. Is it possible to design the App with the Storyboard for a specific screen size e.g. 5.5" in portrait and xcode automaticaly scales proportionaly to the other screen sizes (4 and 4.7)? I tried to use auto layout but then i had to make spezifications for each object. I know its not the best way. But for me as an beginner it would be easyer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can build your app for the 4" and 3.5" screen sizes and have iOS automatically scale up to the new 4.7" and 5.5" phones.  This is the default behavior for apps that were not specifically built with the new sizes accounted for.  Basically to do this build your app as you normally would, but don't include launch image sized for the new phones.  You cannot, however, build it for the 6 Plus or 6 and have it scale down for older phones.  This would result in a poor experience, as tap areas would be made too small on the smaller screens.

Also, be aware that this will be optimized for the older phones, and everything will look igger on the new phones.  If you are building a new app, I highly recommend you take some training on autolayout and you should be able to build most pages to scale to the screen size without having to target specific phones.  The one exception is maybe offering a split screen view on the 6 Plus in landscape, as Apple has done with many of their apps.